# Splitting log files by date or file size in Lighttpd

Tags: logging, lighttpd, logrotate

So far the only way I've found to do this is by telling Lighty to pipe its logs through an app called "vlogger".  Is there a way to break out log files by date without introducing any external dependencies or cron jobs?  I feel like there might be a way to do it with config file variables, but my Lighty-fu just isn't strong enough.

**Edit**: Looks like [logrotate](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/117) may be my best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only know the option to use syslog for log handling or additional software like "logrotate" or something similiar. Perhaps the [manual](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:ModAccessLog) helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how to configure logrotate for lighty: [Lighttpd: Log File Rotation](http://www.phaze9dezign.com/post/9495204210/lighttpd-log-file-rotation)

Answer (score 0):

Im using cronolog instead of vlogger to do this without any problems. Unfortunately, you can't use this technique to rotate the error log. Looking at old Lighttpd bug reports, there was a patch to fix this for error logs but it was rejected upsteam.